# How to configure to group grids in foundation 4

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 4 to grid the invoice page.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="row grid">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <span>Ship To</span>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <span>Order Information</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <span>Content Of ShipTo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <span>Content Of Order Information</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

it shows as a two column table with two rows.

However when I narrow the window, I see two headers goes up and down together. I wish to have the first cell of the second column show under the first cell of first column. How to change the code? Perhaps a nest grid will work but I still like to hear from you guys.

[image: img1]

Currently the narrow effect show like this, which is not I want.
[image: img2]

Comment: Please show us your CSS or even better a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the markup to group headers with their associated content. Instead of what you have, try something like this:

```
<div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
    <div>
        <span>Ship To</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Order Information</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
    <div>
        <span>Content Of ShipTo</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Content Of Order Information</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will keep them stacked in small viewports and side-by-side in larger ones.